# Folium popup gets syntax error message

Tags: python-3.x, popup, folium

I'm new to folium.  I was able to produce the map I wanted from a dataframe.

```
df_map = folium.Map(location=[37.750999450684, -97.821998596191], zoom_start=4)   

for each in df[0:len(df)].iterrows(): 
    folium.CircleMarker(location=[each[1]["GEO_LAT_0"], each[1]["GEO_LNG_0"]],
                    radius=5.0, color='#3186cc', fill_color='#3186cc').add_to(df_map)
```

Map comes out nicely.

Next I wanted to add popups from a third column in data frame, and can't seem to get syntax right.  Not clear how I might add these popups from folium documentation.  An error message I can't interpret results from this code:

```
df_map = folium.Map(location=[37.750999450684, -97.821998596191], zoom_start=4)   

for each in df[0:len(df)].iterrows(): 
    folium.CircleMarker(location=[each[1]["GEO_LAT_0"], each[1]["GEO_LNG_0"]],
                    **popup=each[1]["GEO_CITY_0"],**
                    radius=5.0, color='#3186cc',fill_color='#3186cc').add_to(df_map)
```

To verify my loop and dataframe were ok, I substituted a

```
print each[1]["GEO_CITY_0"]
```

within the for-each loop instead of folium.circlemarker and it worked fine.  Something is wrong when I use the popup syntax above.

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'get_name'
```

Your help appreciated.  Thanks  p.s.  Full message is:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 4, in 
    radius=1, color='#3186cc', fill_color='#3186cc').add_to(df_map)

File "C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\folium\features.py", line 870, in **init**
    super(CircleMarker, self).**init**(location=location, popup=popup)

File "C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\folium\map.py", line 652, in **init**
    self.add_child(popup)

File "C:\Users\Peter\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\branca\element.py", line 96, in add_child
    name = child.get_name()

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'get_name'

Comment: Hi, what version of folium are you using?  I believe this error is expected in earlier versions of folium.  So perhaps you could upgrade or you could do this instead. `popup=folium.Popup(each[1]["GEO_CITY_0"])`

Comment: this [issue](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/259) describes the issue and the change in later versions

Comment: Hi Bob -- Excellent.  Thanks for your comment.  I have version 0.4.0.  I saw the package was update just 2-3 days ago to version 0.5.0. Your syntax is what I needed.  Much appreciated.  I'm not sure how to close a Stack Overflow problem -- I'll look around -- but this one is closed.  Thanks

Comment: Hi pzajonc, Ok, great.  I'm a little confused though as I have 0.4.0 as well and your original syntax works for me.   You should consider submitting an issue for this.  As far as closing this, I will submit an answer and you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was under the impression that @pzajonc's syntax of `popup=each[1]["GEO_CITY_0"]` would work in recent versions (OP's has 0.4.0) of folium.

Here's a github [issue](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/259) that mentions the error and the [fix](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/pull/283)

Regardless, changing it to `popup=folium.Popup(each[1]["GEO_CITY_0"])` will resolve the issue.

Comment: I accept this answer.  Thanks Bob.  (My reputation isn't high enough yet to give the up vote.)  Yes- I thought my syntax popup=each was correct, and it's funny it worked for you, while the alternate syntax popup=Folium.popup(each) that you provided does solve my problem -- I'm operating in Windows 10 under python 3.6

Comment: HI pzajonc, just click on the check mark to the left of my answer